# Facing weird problem while adding and removing class

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have below function which is being used to initialize a widget.

```
jQuery.fn.initPortlet = function( parent_component ,header , component ){
        var o = $(this[0])
        this.addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all")
            .find(header)           
            .addClass("headertitle")
            .addClass("align_center")
            .addClass("defaultheadercolor")
            .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>')
            .end()
            .find(component);
};
```

what it does is append a minus icon at the top left corner of the widget.
i have some ajax call because of that this function get called multiple time and append a minus icon multiple times.

i am tring to re-write this function in such a way, so that how many time it's get called, append only one minus icon into header.
i tried fallowing approach but it didn't work.

```
var $minusthick = $('span.ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick');
$('div.div_header').find($minusthick).remove().prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>').end();
```

what i am tring is remove all span with class name span.ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick and finally append a minus icon, but it's not worked for me.

**Edit**
i am calling this function in this way-

```
$('.div_portlet').initPortlet('.div_portlet','.div_header','.div_content')   
            $('.div_portlet_inner').initPortlet('.div_portlet_inner','.div_header_inner','.div_content_inner');
```

html corresponding to this is-

**html:**

```
<div class="div_portlet" id="LINEITEM_HEADER" >
<div class="div_header"><%=hu.getFrameURL(82,83)%> Line Item Header Information</div>
            <div class="div_content" id="LINEITEM_HEADER_CONTENT">

            </div>  
</div>
```

for second call html will remain  same just classes will get change from `div_portlet` to `div_portlet_inne`r, in the same way for other class.
i have written this function in a js file.

any help or suggestion so that i can achieve my goal will be highly appreciated. 
Please guys help me out i got stuck at this point.
Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: who down voted this question and why?

Comment: Not me, but: can you improve on the question's title? Can you use some punctuation and capital letters in your question's body? It's also quite a vague question, and your example HTML contains what looks like irrelevant ASP. You should produce a full testcase on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Suggest Question title change to: 'How to determine if jquery function has been applied already'

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what variable `o` is being used for - but the general point of my alteration below is to check to see if the class has been applied already, using the jQuery `hasClass()` function.

```
jQuery.fn.initPortlet = function( parent_component ,header , component ){
    var o = $(this[0])

    if (!this.hasClass('ui-widget'))
    {
      this.addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all")
        .find(header)           
        .addClass("headertitle")
        .addClass("align_center")
        .addClass("defaultheadercolor")
        .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>')
        .end()
        .find(component);
    }
};
```

Comment: it doesn't answer my question....my question is how to remove that class if it's already there...i.e. minus-icon..if i will do in this way it will get called only once for distinct argument.

Comment: and i am forced to call this function again and again but that - icon count should be 1.

Comment: Are you doing something else in the `initPortlet` code that you haven't shown? I can understand wanting to call it multiple times if it was updating some dynamic content, but it just seems to apply some static html changes, so please explain why you need to execute the function body multiple times?

Comment: actualy i have main portlet then another portlet inside it, even innerportlet can be more than 1.so i am intializing all these portlet by calling this function...hope now you can understand why i am doing this.if you want i can attach a screenshot of problem..

Answer (score 2):

ʞɔɐɯɹoↃɔW sǝɯɐſ gave a good solution to this problem, but here is an explanation why your attempt didn't work:

The first part of the selector `'span.ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'` is looking for a `span` with class `ui-icon`, as you intended, but the second part looks for an element of type `<ui-icon-minusthick>` which obviously doesn't exist. To select an element with multiple class names, add them all to the same selector just like you would in CSS:

```
$('span.ui-icon.ui-icon-minusthick')
```

Of course, the rest of you code would be a no-op since `find($minusthick)` will do nothing and therefore the rest of the jQuery chain will have no context in which to operate. This would (I think) work as you expected:

```
$('div.div_header').find('span.ui-icon.ui-icon-minusthick').remove().end().prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>');
```

The extra `end()` call returns the jQuery object to the first selector, in this case `div.div_header` and there is no need for the final `end()`.

Comment: +1 I think you answer the OP's question, but I think removing and then re-adding the same identical content is pointless?

Comment: @ʞɔɐɯɹoↃɔW sǝɯɐſ not always, but in this case I'd agree with you, hence why I think you gave a good solution, I just thought it would help the OP to know why their solution didn't work :)

Comment: @Vivek it was from your original code but is unnecessary, have updated answer.

Comment: oh!! sorry....but still it's not working in desired way...i got 2 minus icon when i call it second time..

Comment: @Vivek it's not clear where this 'check' code is being executed, and if it's acting on the correct elements. Where have you included it in your `initPortlet` function? What are the variables being passed to this? You can update the original question so others can also see this.

Comment: @roryf- please see updated question and please tell me what's going wrong?