# how to find a html element and then remove it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facing weird problem while adding and removing class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095815/facing-weird-problem-while-adding-and-removing-class)

Suppose I have the following **html**--

```
     <div class="div_portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all defaultcontentbg portlet-width default_border default_border_color portlet_space">
     <div class="div_header headertitle align_center defaultheadercolor portlet-header-left-padding default_bottom_border default_border_color">
     <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>
      Order Header Level Information</div>
      <div id="ordrHdrLvnInfn" class="div_content portlet-width">
```

What I am trying to do is, check whether span with class `ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick` exists or not, if it exists first remove it and then add it. I tried in following way, but it's not working

**javascript function::**

```
jQuery.fn.initPortlet = function( parent_component ,header , component ){
        this.find(header).find('span.ui-icon').remove();

        this.addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all")
            .find(header)           
            .addClass("headertitle")
            .addClass("align_center")
            .addClass("defaultheadercolor")
            .end()
            .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>')
            .find(component);
                   }
```

and I am calling this function in this way..

```
$('.div_portlet').initPortlet('.div_portlet','.div_header','.div_content')
```

It should first remove the span then add it, but if I am calling this function multiple times then it just keep on adding that span.
How can I do this or is there any better way to do this.
Thanks!!!!

Comment: one suggestion: change `.addClass("headertitle").addClass("align_center").addClass("defaultheadercolor")` to single line `addClass("headertitle align_center defaultheadercolor")`

Comment: @mplungjan-would you please explain? what you want to say?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle?  Are there multiple div_portlets on a page?

Comment: @John Green-yes there are multiple div_portlets on page.

Comment: Does the first one work the way you want?  : )

Comment: yes. but when i call it second time, it breaks

Comment: that's the problem..i want to remove that span first and then trying to add it..so you have any better idea to do this.

Comment: I don't see why the remove wouldn't work.  My thinking is that the function is working as a singleton, as it starts from a multi-item selector ('.div_portlet' -- of which there are many) and isn't properly taking care of that selector at the plugin level.

Comment: @John: the remove isn't working because the span isn't where it is being looked for (see my answer below).

Comment: @Chris - Agreed  Not sure why I missed your fiddle.

Comment: @John: I think if you are just talking in comments then sometimes it doesn't load up new answers. Its why I thought i'd comment since I figured you'd missed it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding your span outside the div_header. Your .end() means you are no longer working with your header filter so the span is getting added to the beginning of your ui_widget...

http://jsfiddle.net/Qjrcg/ is a fiddle of your code. If you look I have a commented out .end() just after the prepend. If you uncomment this and comment out the earlier one then the span (which I put test text in to make it easier to see) only gets created once.

Hopefully this should sort you out.

Comment: thanks buddy, but that's a typo mistake only

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? moving the end around makes the difference between creating lots of spans (as in http://jsfiddle.net/Qjrcg/) and one span (as in http://jsfiddle.net/Qjrcg/1/). If this isn't what you want then can you clarify please? This second bit of code seems to be removing the span and then readding it. This is clearly visible when putting a random number in the span (http://jsfiddle.net/Qjrcg/2).

Comment: yes thanks man for your efforts...yes you are write i did same typo mistake in my jsfile too. thanks a lot..

Comment: no prob. Glad you've got it fixed. :) (and don't forget to mark the answer as accepted)

Comment: oops a little late I suppose anyways +1 :-)

Comment: yeah sure...here you go.... :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your first find

```
this.find(header).find('span.ui-icon').remove();
```

you are trying to find the icon inside the header but you are prepending the next icon to the portlet (this)

```
.prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>')
```

so try this

```
this.find('span.ui-icon').remove();
```

Check out the update which I did to Chris's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qjrcg/5/

HTH